# tessdata folder path issue in Acuant OCR swift

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, tesseract, mrz

I have one test app and a custom framework, in framework i have integrated Acuant OCR (where they use G8 tesseract ). I have added tessdata folder reference in my custom framework [check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN2tL.png) and when i use Cocoapods to add my custom framework and once i run the app its saying file not found.[check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCB0S.png)

```
Error opening data file /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B48E126F-C1D0-44A3-850E-0876773C5784/Test.app/tessdata/OCRB.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'OCRB'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
2021-08-12 12:39:40.197369+0530 Test[4408:1220205] ERROR! Can't init Tesseract engine.
2021-08-12 12:39:40.201508+0530 Test[4408:1220205] Metal API Validation Enabled
```

But when i added the tessdata folder in my test application directly instead of framework then it showed that able to detect tessdata but once i open camera it got crashed with following issue
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLb81.png)

this is how i added tessdata in test application
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWY1G.png)

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Why are you using screenshots to make your points?  Do you use screenshots to run an Xcode project?

Comment: there are some people who doesnt understand